# in zsh, how do you test if an associative array (aka hash table) has a certain property?

Tags: zsh

I want to write a function that returns 0 if the property exists and 1 if it does not.

for example:

```
typeset -A hashtable
hashtable[a]='this is a valid element'
testprop hashtable[a] # returns 0
testprop hashtable[b] # returns 1
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *parameter expansion* `${+name}` almost does, what you want. If `name` is a set parameter `1` is substituted, otherwise `0` is substitued.

To get the desired interface, this can be wrapped into a function:

```sh
function testprop {
    case ${(P)+${1}} in
        0) return 1;;
        1) return 0;;
    esac
}
alias testprop='noglob testprop'
```

#### Explanation:

- The *parameter expansion flag* `P` tells *zsh* to interprete the value `${1}` as further parameter name.
- `${+name}` is substituted by `1` if `name` is set, `0` otherwise.
- The *alias* is necessary so that the parameter to `testprob` does not need to be quoted. Otherwise the square brackets around the index would be interpreted as globbing operator.